# Julia closure with a let block - is this kosher?

Tags: closures, julia

I have cobbled together a closure in Julia using a let block.

```
counter = let
    local counter = 0          # local variable
    f() = counter += 1         # returned function
end

counter(); counter(); counter()
print(counter()) # 4
```

Is this kosher in Julia?

Comment: If your code didn't work like that, the thing wouldn't be called a "closure". "Closing over" `counter` is exactly the intended thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is valid. Here are two alternative ways to get a similar thing:

```
julia> function get_counter()
           counter = 0
           return () -> (counter += 1)
       end
get_counter (generic function with 1 method)

julia> c1 = get_counter()
#1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> c1()
1

julia> c1()
2

julia> c1()
3

julia> mutable struct Counter
           counter::Int
           Counter() = new(0)
       end

julia> (c::Counter)() = (c.counter += 1)

julia> c2 = Counter()
Counter(0)

julia> c2()
1

julia> c2()
2

julia> c2()
3
```

The difference is that `c2` is type stable, while your `counter` and `c1` are not type stable:

```
julia> @code_warntype counter()
Variables
  #self#::var"#f#1"
  counter::Union{}

Body::Any
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :counter)::Core.Box
│   %2 = Core.isdefined(%1, :contents)::Bool
└──      goto #3 if not %2
2 ─      goto #4
3 ─      Core.NewvarNode(:(counter))
└──      counter
4 ┄ %7 = Core.getfield(%1, :contents)::Any
│   %8 = (%7 + 1)::Any
│   %9 = Core.getfield(#self#, :counter)::Core.Box
│        Core.setfield!(%9, :contents, %8)
└──      return %8

julia> @code_warntype c1()
Variables
  #self#::var"#2#3"
  counter::Union{}

Body::Any
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :counter)::Core.Box
│   %2 = Core.isdefined(%1, :contents)::Bool
└──      goto #3 if not %2
2 ─      goto #4
3 ─      Core.NewvarNode(:(counter))
└──      counter
4 ┄ %7 = Core.getfield(%1, :contents)::Any
│   %8 = (%7 + 1)::Any
│   %9 = Core.getfield(#self#, :counter)::Core.Box
│        Core.setfield!(%9, :contents, %8)
└──      return %8

julia> @code_warntype c2()
Variables
  c::Counter

Body::Int64
1 ─ %1 = Base.getproperty(c, :counter)::Int64
│   %2 = (%1 + 1)::Int64
│        Base.setproperty!(c, :counter, %2)
└──      return %2
```

Adding `counter::Int = 0` in your `counter` or `c1` definitions will make it type stable, but you will have Julia do boxing/unboxing anyway. So in conclusion using a functor (`c2` version) is what I would normally opt for. Alternatively you could have made your (or `c1`) version type stable by using `Ref` wrapper like this:

```
julia> counter = let
           local counter = Ref(0)     # local variable
           f() = counter[] += 1         # returned function
       end
(::var"#f#1"{Base.RefValue{Int64}}) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> counter()
1

julia> counter()
2

julia> counter()
3

julia> @code_warntype counter()
Variables
  #self#::var"#f#1"{Base.RefValue{Int64}}

Body::Int64
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :counter)::Base.RefValue{Int64}
│   %2 = Base.getindex(%1)::Int64
│   %3 = (%2 + 1)::Int64
│   %4 = Core.getfield(#self#, :counter)::Base.RefValue{Int64}
│        Base.setindex!(%4, %3)
└──      return %3
```